# How to reference source.yml in a model within a folder in DBT

Tags: yaml, dbt

I am trying to reference a `src.yml` in a model within a folder

here is the structure

```
- dataservice
  - dbt_model
    - models
      - my_folder
        - model_1.sql
      - src.yml
      - dbt_project.yml
```

the src.yml

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: Green
    schema: HistoryGreen
    tables:
      - name: trans
```

I tried using the codes below but they didn't work

```
select * FROM {{ ref ('Green', 'trans') }}
select * FROM {{ source ('Green', 'trans') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

DBT does not yet support namespacing, so all DBT sources and models are universally scoped. You can `ref` or `source` from any model regardless of where the `.yml` file is located in your directory structure and you can refer to it as if it were in the same directory as your model. The only requirements are that the names have to be unique across all config files and they must be under a sub-directory specified in your `model-paths` configuration in `dbt_project.yml`. It doesn't look like you have your full project directory structure posted, but if `dataservice` is not under `models/` (which is the default value in `model-paths`), then it won't be able to find your source ymls.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have updated the folder structure. pls where do I place the src.yml file for my mobile to be able to find it

Comment: According to your update, `src.yml` is under the `models` directory. Your `dbt_project.yml` is in the wrong place though. It should be in the project root. DBT WILL find all `src.yml` files under `models` and you can ref them from anywhere. However, best practice (which I highly recommend) is to put your source files in the same directory as your base models. Then you build other models with `ref`s to the base models.